# SCALA Lift - Access AJAX form values

Tags: ajax, scala, comet, lift

I have the following form:

```
<form class="lift:form.ajax">
<div class="lift:StreamInput">
    <input type="hidden" name="path" value="test" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="james" />
    <input type="hidden" name="level" value="_1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="room" value="demo" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="true" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

Which goes to:

```
object StreamInput {

    def render = {

        var path = ""
        var user = ""
        var level = ""
        var room = ""

        def process(): JsCmd = {

            val message = comet.StreamItem(user, path, level, room)
            StreamServer ! message

        }

        "name=path" #> SHtml.onSubmit(path = _) &
        "name=user" #> SHtml.onSubmit(user = _) &
        "name=level" #> SHtml.onSubmit(level = _) &
        "name=room" #> SHtml.onSubmit(room = _) &
        "name=hidden" #>  SHtml.hidden(process)

    }

}
```

However when I submit the form the values passed to the process method are empty. What am I missing that would cause them to be lost?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not able to test it right now but it could be that `SHtml.onSubmit` does not work in an Ajax context. If you look at the documentation, `SHtml.onSubmit` is only used in the non-Ajax example. The Ajax examples use `SHtml.text` to bind a callback to the text input fields.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm using hidden inputs so when I use SHtml.text it seems to replace them all with standard inputs. Should I be using SHtml.hidden ? If so how would I use it in this context? Thanks

Comment: Hi, yes but when I do "SHtml.hidden(room = _)" I get a compiler error, I'm obviously not using it correctly?

Comment: The docs say you must supply a default value then: `SHtml.hidden(room = _, "defaultValue")`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Finally got a working form :) Just one last thing before I accept your answer, I've currently got a redundant hidden input called hidden thats bound to the process method, is there anyway I can get rid of this and bind the process method to one of the others? Thanks again :)

Comment: You could just append `"name=room" #> (SHtml.hidden(room = _, "defaultValue") ++ SHtml.hidden(process))`.